# mysql query not correct filtering date in past month

Tags: mysql

I've a problem with this MySQL query in Moodle. It returns records from January and February where it should only return records from January.

```
SELECT c.shortname AS Course, g.name AS Project, u.username AS Student, 

FROM_UNIXTIME(u.firstaccess, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Logindate
FROM prefix_course AS c

JOIN prefix_groups AS g ON g.courseid = c.id
JOIN prefix_groups_members AS m ON g.id = m.groupid
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON m.userid = u.id

WHERE c.id = 8 AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.firstaccess), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '15-01-2016' AND '31-01-2016'
```

When I change the dates to e.g. '01-02-2016' AND '15-02-2016' it returns the correct records from February. I've tried several things but I can't filter out the records from only January 2016.

Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: use '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-01-15' AND '2016-01-31'

Comment: or use your format command on the between fields for consistency: BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-01-15'), '%d-%m-%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-01-31'), '%d-%m-%Y')

Comment: Thx, the first answer works fine!